# How do I group a Kaplan Meier and a geom_line under one legend with linetype?

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis

I'm trying to plot a KM with some parametric survival estimates. I have to keep the plot black and white so I'm unable to colour code the lines, however, when I change from `color=key`  to `linetype=key` in the `aes` function in `geom_line`  I get two separate legends titled "1" and "Strata" as shown in the picture below. I was also wondering if it's possible to change the colour of the KM to black and confidence intervals to grey.[image: KM]

```
treatment <- data.frame(
  treatment = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
  t = c(5.525, 1.9493, 4.9473, 5.9466, 1.5797, 0.5038), 
  event = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
)

tempsurv1 <- c(1.0000000, 0.9129731, 0.8337045, 0.7614860, 0.6956758, 0.6356917, 0.50, 0.43, 0.37)
tempsurv2 <- c(1.0000000, 0.9324888, 0.8671987, 0.8042297, 0.7436717, 0.6856045, 0.6300962, 0.5772029, 0.5269681)
x<- c(0:8)
temp <- data.frame(x, tempsurv1, tempsurv2)

temp<- temp %>% 
  gather(key, value, -c(x))

f2 <- survfit(Surv(t, event)~1, data=treatment)
f2 <- ggsurvplot(f2, legend="right") 
f2 <- f2$plot +  geom_line(data = temp, aes(x=x, y=value, group=key, linetype=key))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom");f2
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  You need to give both the `color` and `linetype` scales the same `name`.  I can't run your code as you've not given us the `control` data frame.

Comment: Sorry, the data was meant to be treatment, I've edited it now

Answer (score 2):

It turns out you can get almost exactly what you want by using parameters to the ggsurvplot`call.  (I don't like having the legend label "in the middle".) working out how to get it right, may need looking at the guts of`ggsurvplot`, but I'm happy to be told otherwise.

```
f2 <- ggsurvplot(f2, legend="right", palette = c("#AAAAAA"), legend.name="Strata") 
f2 <- f2$plot +  geom_line(data = temp, aes(x=x, y=value, linetype=key))+
  theme_light() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  scale_linetype_discrete(name="Strata") 
f2
```

Gives

[image: Greyscale output]

I wasn't sure what you meant by "when I change from `key=color` to `key=linetype` I get two separate legends" because neither option appears in your code.

You need to add

```
library(tidyverse)
library(survival)
library(survminer)
```

at the top of yor code to make it a MWE.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear as I switched the RHS and LHS, but key=linetype is the last argument in the geom_line function. Yes, that is very close to what I needed, I just wanted the KM to be under the same legend as the two geom_lines, in other words, the All group to be on the right of Strata.